# A standard method to trace and log which software creates and accesses files on my system?

Tags: mac, security, dtrace

Is there a way to continually trace/log which software is creating and accessing files on my system?

I assume these log files would grow very large unless trimmed.

I see a bunch of dot files and no way to know what application or installation created these files.

For instance in Application Support
`~/Library/Application Support/`

[image]

I have tried using some Terminal commands to get information:
`od -tx1`
`file`
`strings`
`man`
`info`

The impetus for this question is the prevalence of malware, tracking software, caches, etc - so a regular user can know the providence of the files on their system. I believe the system admin term for this process called Auditing.

I am aware that many software vendors store license info inside dot files on the system.

Comment: In **Terminal**: `man fs_usage`

Comment: @user3439894 I read through the man page. Don't see a way to trace what process created a file in the past.

Comment: You did fire off, at my count, 5 questions. @user3439894 provided an answer for your first question and, by implication, your second (yes). That was what you asked. Perhaps you could change your post to a simpler set of questions which make it clear that you are only interested in getting information about past file access.

Comment: @Gilby I asked a main question and a closely related follow up. Is there a limit? “Is there a way to continually trace/log which software is creating and accessing files on my system?”

Comment: I think that @user3439894 answered that question and yet you seemed (to me) in your comment to be dismissing it because you wanted to see past file access. Q1: already answered, Q2: yes, Q3: not overly though it will fill up your disk if you save the output. Q4: the regular user is not supposed to worry about it. Q5: Yes it is part of auditing computer activity.  I am not competent to give a full answer regarding file auditing which requires turning on auditing features (and saving results) and then analysis.

Comment: Re Auditing I can find https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/304893/find-out-if-any-files-were-exported-from-my-macbook/304981#304981 and https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/12735/os-x-private-folder-runaway-file-crash-recovery-126-61gb/12757#12757 which relate to using the OpenBSM Audit system included in macOS. This is a complex topic - I know about it, but have never used it.

Comment: @Gilby thanks for the clue. I will look into that. Sometimes all it takes is knowing the proper terminology - having half the question answered. OpenBSM is exactly what I was thinking of. There must be a reason Apple sets limited logging as default - probably because of log file size and performance.

Answer (score 2):

@Gilby provided an answer that fits the question perfectly... OpenBSM developed by Apple.

Resources available:

[Quick and Dirty OpenBSM Auditing In macOS](https://krypted.com/mac-os-x/quick-dirty-openbsm-auditing-macos/) 
[A high-level evaluation of the OpenBSM audit system in OS X](https://tramdas.wordpress.com/2016/08/05/a-high-level-evaluation-of-the-openbsm-audit-system-in-os-x/)
[AUDIT IN A OS X SYSTEM](https://www.scip.ch/en/?labs.20150108)
[Reading Mac BSM Audit Logs](https://crucialsecurity.wordpress.com/2012/05/17/reading-mac-bsm-audit-logs-2/)
[Getting Cozy With OpenBSM Auditing On MacOS - Patrick Wardle](https://archive.org/details/youtube-CqlpJ7rIT6M)

Question and answer on StackExchange:

[OS X Private Folder - Runaway file "crash recovery" 126.61GB!](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/12735/os-x-private-folder-runaway-file-crash-recovery-126-61gb) 
[Find out if any files were exported from my MacBook](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/304893/find-out-if-any-files-were-exported-from-my-macbook/304981#304981)